# Special tables in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a table that will store an **ID** and a list of **items** that ID has. I want to be able to store multiple IDs in the table, each with a list of items they own, but the amount of items will be different for each ID. Is this possible? Or will I have to make a table for every ID to store their items. The amount of items for each ID will be different still, so I'm not sure how I'd do it either way. *The list of items are stored in an array.* I'm going to have the user click an 'update' button, which I want to find thier ID in the database, then overwrite their old list of items with the new one.

I have been stuck on this for a long time, the more specific answer of how I could do this or helping me, the better. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds more like a document approach than relational.  Make that value column a blob and serialize JSON to it.

Comment: Without knowing the overall scope of what you're trying to do it would be impossible for us to make recommendations for how to design this table. Overall this is a bad question fro StackOverflow. Please read [How to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @JayBlanchard Well I have already asked 2 other questions just like this with much more information on what I wanted and didn't get any answers, don't blame me for rewording my question to try and get some help because no one would help me before...

Comment: @duffymo That seems quite simple, it may work. Thanks, I will try it.

Comment: *"Is this possible?"* Yes. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ You're right - it *is* answerable.

Comment: A document approach presumes that you'll always use the blob/document in its entirety without having to parse it to query.  You SELECT it only using the id primary key.  The moment you have a use case where you want to SELECT by looking at items in the list you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to store everything for an ID in a single record? While technically possible with mysql's [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, it is bad for performance. A better idea would be to use a link table, with a record for each item per ID. As long as your ID column is an index, it's going to outperform FIND_IN_SET any time. MySQL itself does not know arrays, so you will need to serialize the data to either php serialized strings, json, comma separated values or any other structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When you say I should "use a link table, with a record for each item per ID", what exactly do you mean? I currently have a table with a user's ID as the index, and a table which contains all possible items. Do you mean make a table that have the schema: **->id** **->item** and the data would be like: id:1 item:1 id:1 item:3 id:2 item:1

Comment: Exactly. One row in the table would be [ ID: 1, Item: 1 ], another [ ID: 1, Item: 42 ]. You could put a combined UNIQUE index on the columns, so that an ID can only ever have the same item once.

Comment: Okay cool, also, doing it this way I wouldn't have to serialize the data, would I? I could parse it straight into the database with say, a foreach loop, adding an [ID, Item] for each item in the inventory. This seems like a good idea, thanks. Do you think doing it this way, or serializing JSON and de-serializing it when I call the data would be better? It's probably just subjective for what data I'm going to call...

Comment: Databases are very good at keeping lists of numbers and the relations between them. Databases suck at searching is blobs of data for possible text matches. Serializing the items at the user level is something you could do (look up denormalization) as a way of optimizing your site performance. But you probably do not need it yet and I do not recommend it. Also, be sure to properly educate yourself on this subject before attempting it.

Comment: I don't think I will try to denormalize my database. Though with the serialization, I meant just the array of items a user owns, then saving that as a blob, linked to the Id, so: [ID, item_array_JSON]. That way I could still search using the key ID, but the list would all be in one row. I could get the JSON then decode it. That seems to me like it would be better, taking up less rows, unless I had to do calls for specific items a user has. I don't think I will have to do that though.